# LayoutManager is not updated even after called within Handler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My situation is the following: I have a RecyclerView in which I want to insert data.

I add data one by one until the RecyclerView is full. The data comes from a web service.

This is the code I use:

```
@Override
public void receive(Response response) {

    _adapter.add(response.getData());

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            fetchIfNotFull();
        }   
    });
}

private void fetchIfNotFull() {

    if (_layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == _layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1)
        fetchData(); // this will call receive(Response) when it's done
}
```

The problem is that, when I run the application, the RecyclerView is not filled, like I expect (but sometimes it does!).

I found out that `_layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()` does not always return the correct value (the one I expect at least), whereas `_layoutManager.getItemCount()` does, so no more data are fetched...

I thought that wrapping the call inside the `Handler` would help, so it would be called after the next layout update, but it didn't do the trick.

And here is the strange thing: If I call `handler.postDelayed()` with 1000 milliseconds, it works fine! (I didn't try other values), because the layout **was** updated after that time. But I don't like this solution (hack). Is there a way to make sure that the `LayoutManager` has been updated?

Answer (score -1):

After the line

```
_adapter.add(response.getData());
```

add this one

```
_adapter.notifyItemChanged(_adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Comment: `_adapter.add()` already does it internally. I did not mention that `response.getData()` returns a list. Here's how `add()` is defined:

public void add(List<Data> dataSet) {
    int oldSize = _dataSet.size();
    _dataSet.addAll(dataSet);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize, dataSet.size());
}

But if I change `notifyItemRangeInserted` to `notifyDataSetChanged`, it works! How?

I also noticed you used `notifyItemChanged`. Why not `notifyItemInserted`?

Comment: Internally both calls one function `notifyItemRangeInserted(position, 1)`, so it doesn't matter